# GetCostAndUsageWithResources mehtod is not available in JAVA SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

Here I used AWS java SDK for the programmatic access and when I try to call `getCostAndUsageWithResources`, it is not available. But in java documentation it is mentioned that `getCostAndUsageWithResources` method is available ([Link for the Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/costexplorer/model/GetCostAndUsageWithResourcesRequest.html)).

Maven Dependency :-

```
<groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
<artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
<version>1.11.728</version>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've added is only a parent POM. The SDK itself is splited in [dozens](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.amazonaws) of JARs, usually one per service. Try this one for costexplorer:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-costexplorer</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.728</version>
</dependency>
```